Does accesing a file "random" and updating just a part of a file really updates record randomly on hard drive?
I use Visual Basic 6.0. It is possible "Processing Files with Older File I/O" as it is said using VB6. Files can be reached as "random" using this I/O. It gives opportunity to read and write parts of the file. I wonder if just a -random- part of a file is changed using this I/O, is it really be updated just that part of the record on hard drive, or whole changed file is recorded, i.e. written from beginnig to end.

The file is all mapped to clusters.  Under normal circumstances, those clusters won't be replaced, only added to.  No, the whole file won't be rewritten but good question.  This question is terrible (format).  You should take the tour should you choose to post again.  Have a great day.

@Señor CMasMas Thanks first. I really ask, where should I ask this question or in which way? Why is it terrible by format? Thanks for help.

Sure.  I am glad you asked.  First, I will tell you the reason it is important is so other people in the future can search this site and find the same question in a readable format.  I suggest you take a peak at how to ask a good question and you will see what I mean.  The tour is not as useful in that regard (IMHO).

If you randomly grab a few questions from the main page, you will immediately know the difference.  Very Good ... Meh .. To see bad ones, look for negative scores.


I use Visual Basic 6.0. It is possible "Processing Files with Older File I/O" as it is said using VB6. Files can be reached as "random" using this I/O. It gives opportunity to read and write parts of the file. I wonder if just a -random- part of a file is changed using this I/O, is it really be updated just that part of the record on hard drive, or whole changed file is recorded, i.e. written from beginnig to end.

Yes, it can update just that part – programs can directly seek to and write individual bytes.
The OS handles it with a minimum granularity of a 'cluster' or 'block' or 'allocation unit', which is often 4 kB or a similar power-of-two (chosen when formatting the file system). Though depends on the OS and the file system; certain "copy on write" filesystems such as ZFS might rewrite an entire 'record' (which could be as large as 128 kB or even 4 MB).
The absolute minimum for disk random access is usually one disk sector, typically either 512 bytes or 4096 bytes for HDDs. (On SSDs it is physically larger but they nevertheless emulate 512-byte sectors in their firmware.)
So if you update a single byte, the OS will need to read and rewrite at least a 512-byte sector – but generally not the whole file.
